# Hibernate Multi-table Bulk Operations always try to create the temporary table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, inheritance

I have some entities using join-inheritance and I'm doing bulk operations on them. As explained in [Multi-table Bulk Operations](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/MultitableBulkOperations) Hibernate uses a temporary table to execute the bulk operations.

As I understand temporary tables the data in them is temporary (deleted at end of transaction or session) but the table themselves are permanent. What I see is that Hibernate tries to create the temporary table every time such a query is executed. Which in my case is up more than 35.000 times per hour. The create table statement obviously fails every time, because a table with that name already exists. This is really unnecessary and probably hurts the performance, also the DBAs are not happy...

Is there a way that Hibernate remembers that it already created the temporary table?

If not, are there any workarounds? My only idea is to use single-table-inheritance instead to avoid using temporary tables completely.

Hibernate version is 4.2.8, DB is Oracle 11g.

Comment: When you say `The create table statement obviously fails every time`, are you getting any log when you set log level to `debug`? log something like `Error attempting to export...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug in [TemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.8.Final/org/hibernate/hql/spi/TemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java#TemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy), because when using the [Oracle8iDialect](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.8.Final/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle8iDialect.java#Oracle8iDialect.dropTemporaryTableAfterUse%28%29) says that temporary tables shouldn't be deleted:

```
@Override
public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
    return false;
}
```

But this check is made only when deleting the table:

```
protected void releaseTempTable(Queryable persister, SessionImplementor session) {
    if ( session.getFactory().getDialect().dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() ) {
        TemporaryTableDropWork work = new TemporaryTableDropWork( persister, session );
        if ( shouldIsolateTemporaryTableDDL( session ) ) {
            session.getTransactionCoordinator()
                    .getTransaction()
                    .createIsolationDelegate()
                    .delegateWork( work, shouldTransactIsolatedTemporaryTableDDL( session ) );
        }
        else {
            final Connection connection = session.getTransactionCoordinator()
                    .getJdbcCoordinator()
                    .getLogicalConnection()
                    .getConnection();
            work.execute( connection );
            session.getTransactionCoordinator()
                    .getJdbcCoordinator()
                    .afterStatementExecution();
        }
    }
    else {
        // at the very least cleanup the data :)
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            final String sql = "delete from " + persister.getTemporaryIdTableName();
            ps = session.getTransactionCoordinator().getJdbcCoordinator().getStatementPreparer().prepareStatement( sql, false );
            session.getTransactionCoordinator().getJdbcCoordinator().getResultSetReturn().executeUpdate( ps );
        }
        catch( Throwable t ) {
            log.unableToCleanupTemporaryIdTable(t);
        }
        finally {
            if ( ps != null ) {
                try {
                    session.getTransactionCoordinator().getJdbcCoordinator().release( ps );
                }
                catch( Throwable ignore ) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but now when creating the table:

```
protected void createTempTable(Queryable persister, SessionImplementor session) {
    // Don't really know all the codes required to adequately decipher returned jdbc exceptions here.
    // simply allow the failure to be eaten and the subsequent insert-selects/deletes should fail
    TemporaryTableCreationWork work = new TemporaryTableCreationWork( persister );
    if ( shouldIsolateTemporaryTableDDL( session ) ) {
        session.getTransactionCoordinator()
                .getTransaction()
                .createIsolationDelegate()
                .delegateWork( work, shouldTransactIsolatedTemporaryTableDDL( session ) );
    }
    else {
        final Connection connection = session.getTransactionCoordinator()
                .getJdbcCoordinator()
                .getLogicalConnection()
                .getConnection();
        work.execute( connection );
        session.getTransactionCoordinator()
                .getJdbcCoordinator()
                .afterStatementExecution();
    }
}
```

As a workaround, you could extend the Oracle dialect and override the `dropTemporaryTableAfterUse` method to return `false`.

I filled the [HHH-9744](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9744) issue for this.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. You mean override to return `true`? I fear that it would be even more inefficient to drop and create the table all the time than just having it fail when trying to create it. I'm also not sure if this would be isolated from other transactions. A better workaround might be adding `if not exists` but that isn't supported for global temporary tables. Maybe I can tell Hibernate to use my own TemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy and cache which temporary tables it already created. What do you think?

Comment: Sure you can. You can extend `TemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy`, override the `createTempTable` method to take into bypass the table creation andthen configure the new strategy via the `hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy` property. I'd appreciate if you can supply a test case and a possible code-change proposal to the Hibernate issue.

Comment: Test case isn't easy, because Hibernate just swallows the exception I'm afraid. I'm not really qualified to propose a fix, but look at my answer for a really simple possible workaround.

Comment: The operation is not atomic. I would include the check-and-act inside a lock. To speed things up, you can use a double-check lock, so that the lock is only taken if there is no table already created.

Comment: You're right, but I don't worry too much about it, if Hibernate tries to create the table a few times at the start of the application. What i don't want is permanently 10tries/sec. :)

Answer (score 1):

With Vlad pointing me in the right direction I came up with the following workaround to cache the names of already created temporary tables:

```
public class FixedTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy extends TemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy {

    private final Set<String> tables = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    @Override
    protected void createTempTable(Queryable persister, SessionImplementor session) {
        final String temporaryIdTableName = persister.getTemporaryIdTableName();
        if (!tables.contains(temporaryIdTableName)) {
            super.createTempTable(persister, session);
            tables.add(temporaryIdTableName);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used by setting the property `hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy` to the fully qualified name of this class.

Please not that this is not a general solution and only works if the database/dialect uses global temporary tables (opposed to session/transaction specific).